# How to show a video player on aspx page dynamically

Tags: .net, asp.net, html

I have an application and In my home page I want to show a video, and the URL of this video I want to set dynamically. Can someone tell me How Can I do this.
I have tried YoutubePlayer control from codeplex but it work fine with youtube not with the URL that I want it to work.
I have tried ASP-Net-Video control as well but it shows a tooltip 
Can any one tell me how I can create object to play video and how can I set the path of the video dynamically

Answer (score 2):

You could try [Flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org/). It's one of the most popular and widely-used players available.

Flowplayer provides rich JavaScript and Flash APIs to allow for easy customization and rapid integration. Check out [the documentation](http://flowplayer.org/documentation/api/index.html) for specific details.

Comment: yes but I want to assign the video url dynamically from the page can I do that

Comment: Nathan If u can probably show me a demo how to use it can save my time in the mean while I m trying my best to do it

Comment: Nathan everything is fine but u know what it supports limited media format. suggest me something else

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [HTML5 video player](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_video.asp).  You can then change the path to the video easily both server or client side.